# How close can garage overhead storage be to fire sprinklers?

Tags: garage, storage, building-regulations, fire-sprinkler

I've recently been looking at getting overhead storage racks for my garage which has several standard pendant sprinklers.  The racks I am looking at are 4' x 8' and have rigid brackets, vertical posts, horizontal beams and crosshatched wire base.  I asked the local installer what the distance requirements are so I can measure and calculate how many racks I would be able to install.

I received a response stating that all I need is 5" horizontal clearance from each rack to each sprinkler.  Is this correct?  The reason I ask is that [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/8393) regarding light fixture distance from fire sprinklers has a distinctly different answer.

The answer from JayL contains the following:

> The residential code says pendant sprinklers must be at least 3 ft from obstructions such as ceiling fans and lights (as measured from their centers)

Does the above apply to storage racks as well?  Are they getting by with a technicality where it's within code as long as you don't put anything on the racks, but as soon as you put a storage bin up there it becomes an obstruction and out of code?

Edit:  For clarity's sake, the brackets for these racks are mounted to the roof ceiling joists and the vertical posts hang down from the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You should not store any items within 18" of the ceiling near a sprinkler head. The items can obstruct the water flow of the sprinkler if it goes off.

> NFPA 13 (2013), Clearance to Storage, has a requirement in 8.5.6.1,
>   which states, "Unless the requirements of 8.5.6.2, 8.5.6.3, 8.5.6.4, or
>   8.5.6.5 are met, the clearance between the deflector and the top
>   of storage or contents of the room shall be 18 in. (457 mm) or
>   greater."
>
> OSHA  29 CFR 1910.159(c)(10) in part states, "The minimum vertical
>   clearance between sprinklers and material below shall be 18-inches
>   (457 mm).
>
> The 18" should be considered a minimum vertical clearance. All items
>   in the storage area must fall below this plane

Comment: The NFPA 13 cite you were after is 8.5.6.1 not 8.5.6.4 (8.5.6.4 only applies to sprinklers especially tested for closely piled storage, I'm looking at the 2013 ed. btw)

Comment: You are correct. As I stated in my answer.... 8.5.6.1 states that "Unless the requirements of .2-.5 are met, the 18" rule applies.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question/answer, but isn't he asking about overhead storage attached to the ceiling and horizontal distance from a sprinkler head? The 18" makes sense coming from below vertically - but is it 5" for racks attached to the ceiling? Or is it also 18" horizontally as well?